# how can i set edit configuration in android studio?

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

i'm trying to set configuration

document said i should set module(which is my app)

like this image

[image]

but in my android studio configuration

there is no module only option i have is

like this

[image]

what should i do??

Comment: Which document have you followed? and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: this document https://developer.android.com/studio/run/rundebugconfig 

and i tried to change include ':app' ->  include: "app"  in my project file (setting gradel) but it doesn't work

Comment: sorry, but May I know what is the motto behind the change in configurations?

Comment: i want to add keystore

Comment: I think you are about to generate a signed build ?

Comment: but there is  no generate sign apk in bulid

Comment: Keystore is used to update the version of app to plat store or create a new sign app..

Comment: Try this https://www.programmersought.com/article/14913886567/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

click "+" icon which is on top of templates and select Android app and then press apply and close out of that configuration window and reopen and then select module it should be visible there if it doesn't that means module is not correctly set or IDE cannot identify.

once you created project it should auto generate run/debug configuration if not try build from Build button or build menu it should work